# How do I create a custom placemark icon using winforms-geplugin API? (using C# not Javascript)

Tags: c#, google-earth-plugin

I'm using the following code to create a placemark in my C# project.

```
kmlTreeView.ParseKmlObject(
     KmlHelpers.CreatePlacemark(ge,
                                Coord,
                                d.sSerialNumber,    // ID (ESN)
                                d.sNickname,     // Name - shown in tree
                                "Device Type: " + d.sName + "\n" +
                                "IP Address: " + d.sIPAddress + "\n" + 
                                "ESN: " + d.sSerialNumber)); // shown in bubble
```

What I can't figure out is how to change the icon from the standard yellow pushpin.  All the javascript examples I've seen use ge.createIcon() and ge.createStyle().  Those functions don't appear to be available in the managed code API.

Is there some other way to access the placemark object that I haven't been able to find?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  Using the example javascript here -(https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/placemarks#custom) - I just changed the single quotes (') to double quotes (") and it worked perfectly.

```
                dynamic placemark = KmlHelpers.CreatePlacemark(
                      ge,
                      Coord,
                      d.sSerialNumber,    // ID (ESN)
                      d.sNickname,     // Name - shown in tree
                      "Device Type: " + d.sName + "\n" +
                      "IP Address: " + d.sIPAddress + "\n" + 
                      "ESN: " + d.sSerialNumber);
                var icon = ge.createIcon("");
                icon.setHref("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png");
                var style = ge.createStyle(string.Empty);
                style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon);
                style.getIconStyle().setScale(5.0);
                placemark.setStyleSelector(style);
```